# How to fix image builder internal exception in android?

Tags: android, exception, resources

I imported a project from my friend
but it always had a red cross in the project explore on eclipse
The project was built automatically, thus I check the error log.
and here's the following exception

[image]

I googled it but failed to find any solution...
anybody knows why?

BTW, is it okay if my package name contains capitalized word?

Comment: what's your package name dear... it usally starts with lower case

Comment: The package name is correct. check my answer.